# Cannot read property of undefined (reading 'map') - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to populate the data from my mock data which is in json format. When I am trying to run the component I am getting undefined reading map error. I have checked that my component is rendering with the value only. Even it's rendering with the value I am getting this undefined error. I have tried to applied conditional rendering but that doesn't help me.  I checked other solutions which is having the same issue but nothing helps me. Any can guide me where I am missing the point. Thanks in advance.

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import mockData from './mock-data/mock-select';

    const createCell = cell => ({ key: cell.key, children: cell.title });
    
    const createCellsForRow = cells => cells.map(cell => createCell(cell)); -----> I am getting error from here(undefined reading map)
    
    const StTable = () => {
      const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState([]);
    
      const handleRowToggle = (event, metaData) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (selectedKey !== metaData.key) {
          setSelectedKey(metaData.key);
        }
      };
    
      const createRow = rowData => (
        {
          key: rowData.key,
          cells: createCellsForRow(rowData.cells),
          toggleAction: {
            metaData: { key: rowData.key },
            onToggle: handleRowToggle,
            isToggled: selectedKey === rowData.key,
            toggleLabel: rowData.toggleText,
          },
        }
      );
    
      const createRows = data => data.map(childItem => createRow(childItem));
    
      return (
        <Table
          summaryId="example-single-select"
          summary="This table shows an implementation of single row selection."
          numberOfColumns={4}
          cellPaddingStyle="standard"
          rowStyle="toggle"
          dividerStyle="horizontal"
          headerData={{
            selectAllColumn: {
              checkLabel: 'Single Selection',
            },
            cells: [
              { key: 'cell-0', id: 'toggle-0', children: 'Name' },
              { key: 'cell-1', id: 'toggle-1', children: 'Address' },
              { key: 'cell-2', id: 'toggle-2', children: 'Phone Number' },
              { key: 'cell-3', id: 'toggle-3', children: 'Email Id' },
            ],
          }}
          bodyData={[
            {
              rows: createRows(mockData),
            },
          ]}
        />
      );
    };
    
    export default StTable;

    //MockDataSample
    [
    {"SNO":001, "SregID":"SOO1", "Status": "Available"},
    {"SNO":002, "SregID":"SOO2", "Status": "Not Available"},
    {"SNO":003, "SregID":"SOO3", "Status": "Available"},
    ]
```

Comment: Where is the mockData ?

Comment: It looks like you are calling the `map` function on something that isn't an array. In the code sample you provided it is either in `createCellsForRow` or in `createRows`. Could you share the full stack trace?

Comment: do `console.log(rowData.cells)` inside your `createRow` function to make sure if it is actually an array

Comment: @jon doe, for createRow  I am getting the data from mockData, based on this createCellsForRow needs to updated based on createRow

Comment: @AdityaParab, I couldn't do console on that function.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `rows: createRows(mockData)` your `data` inside of the `createRows` function looks like this -

```
[
    {"SNO":001, "SregID":"SOO1", "Status": "Available"},
    {"SNO":002, "SregID":"SOO2", "Status": "Not Available"},
    {"SNO":003, "SregID":"SOO3", "Status": "Available"},
]
```

Inside of your `createRows`, when you call `data.map()` each `childItem` is an item inside of the data array which is an object.
Then, you call `createRow(childItem)` on each child item, so inside of `createRow` `rowData` is an object from the `mockData` array. Inside of `createRow` you call `createCellsForRow(rowData)` which is undefined since `rowData` is just `{"SNO":001, "SregID":"SOO1", "Status": "Available"}`, so when you call `cells.map()` inside of `createCellsForRow` `cells` is just undefined.

Comment: could you please assist me what I need to do to resolve this